# How to make Work Management Service syncing using hints

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Work Management Service (WMS) uses hints to sync tasks. As a fallback WMS uses search (every 3 hours) to find tasks.
My newly assigned tasks are available in my aggegrated task list on me personal site only after waiting for 3 hours. This indicates the hints system is not working properly.
What is required to make the hints system work?
The 'internet' is only telling me that there is an event receiver on all task lists that is responsible for this, but I only see the following:

Name  : HierarchyTaskListItemEventHandler
Type  : ItemAdding
Class : Microsoft.SharePoint.Applications.HierarchyTasksList.SPHierarchyTaskListItemEventReceiver

Name  : HierarchyTaskListItemEventHandler
Type  : ItemUpdating
Class : Microsoft.SharePoint.Applications.HierarchyTasksList.SPHierarchyTaskListItemEventReceiver

Name  : TaskListItemAdded
Type  : ItemAdded
Class : Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.TaskListNewsFeedEventReceiver

Name  : TaskListItemUpdated
Type  : ItemUpdated
Class : Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.TaskListNewsFeedEventReceiver

Answer (score 0):

Ah, turns out Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.TaskListNewsFeedEventReceiver is responsible for this!
Using ILSpy I now see which logging I should monitor. TaskListNewsFeedEventReceiver.UpdateHintsLocally is the key.

It's all at the Medium or Verbose level in the Runtime category. Search for 'wmahint' helps.
After adjusting the ULS logging level, I now found an exception (UnauthorizedAccessException).

It seems like the application pool account of the portal webapplication needs access to the mysite webapplication.

I used this:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://mysite
$wa.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity("domain\portal-apppool-account")
```

It works, not sure if this is the best solution though.